# Retrieving some divs in a list using Jquery

Tags: jquery, list, html, toggle

My question will seem very simple : suppose I have a list of divs that share the same class 'myClass'. Using Jquery, I would like to store in a variable the $i-th first divs (where i is an arbitrary integer) in order to manipulate them in one single time (adding class, toggling to all of these). How can I do that ?

Comment: `$i-th first`? Do you mean every `$i-th` element in the list?

Comment: Could you show some representative HTML, and clearly explain what you want to do/happen (and in response to what event)?

Comment: Suppose i=10, I mean the ten first divs

Comment: I tried to use push() to create an array of the divs, but it seemed complicated

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var i=6;
$(".myClass").slice(0,i).each(function(){
       //do whatever you want here. 
       //`this` is a jQuery object of the div element. For example:
       $(this).addClass("newClass");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to act on several elements you've got a few options, assuming that `$(selector)` returns a valid selection of elements, and `i` holds the relevant number:

```
// hides all divs greater than the `i`-th
$(selector + ':gt(' + i + ')').hide();
```

[Generic JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/SWRbz/).
Or:

```
// hides all divs less than the `i`-th
$(selector + ':lt(' + i + ')').hide();
```

[Generic JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/SWRbz/1/).

Obviously use whatever jQuery method you require in place of `hide()`.

References:

- [`:gt()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/).
- [`:lt()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/).